# data insertion in 2D array in jquery

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, 2d

I want to insert data in array through jQuery like below:

Means at first time insert values on first position only and second time  insert values on second postion (i.e not insert values together at a time on both positions)

```
    var custArr = new Array();
    custArr.push(["Structure", "Select Parent"]);
    custArr.push(["A", ""]);
    custArr.push(["B", ""]);

    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');

    for (var i = 0; i < custArr.length; i++) 
    {
       custArr.push("", sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', "some values");
    }
```

Expected result is:

```
custArr.push(["Structure", sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', "some values")]);
```

I cannot insert them both together that is the problem so firstly in first loop. I can insert only structure values and in second loop I need to insert a dropdown in front of structure values.

Comment: Is expected result of `custArr.push(["Structure", "Select Parent"]);` `[["Structure"], ["Select Parent"]]` ?

Comment: Your code is missing a paranthesis on line 7, also, I don't think you intended to push sel.append to your array.

Comment: expected result is custArr.push(["Structure", sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', "some values")]); i can not insert them both together that is the problem so firstly in first loop i can insert only structure values and in second loop i need to insert a dropdown in front of structure values